# HttpWebRequest error supporting encoding of type chunked

Tags: .net, encoding, httpwebrequest, decode

I made a code so download a page so uses the chunked encoding, but the result is not good - a ����� characters.

I looked at fiddler - there the characters are correct.

How can I get the correct characters with keeping stuff simple? (no manual parsing)

Or - how can I tell to the server so we not support this encoding?

Thanks in advance

Here is the code in C#

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.grad-nk.ru/arti/531.php");

var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

using (Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
   using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
   {
      var content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
   }
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is the line so makes it work

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(webResponse.CharacterSet)))
```

Thanks to wal!!!

Comment: Is there are charset specified in the Content-Type header of the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Content-Type` of that page is [windows-1251](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) so you will have to use that Encoding when reading the response from the stream.

Change this line in your code:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
```

to this:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))
```

which will fix your problem.